# unix awk begin statement

Tags: awk

I was trying to use a begin statement in awk, but somehow the begin statement is printed on top of every record instead of the very first record that I wanted. I am not very sure why, it would be grateful if someone can give me some opinions as to what goes wrong in my code.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" }{print "MARKER\tCHR\tBP\tEA\tNEA\tEAF\tP\tOR\tSE\tOR_95L\tOR95U\tN\tN_CASES\tN_CONTROLS\tSTRAND\tINFO\tHWE_P\tIMPUTED"}FNR>16 && $45!="NA" && $9>=0.4 { if ($1=="---") print $2,"'"$chr"'",$4,$6,$5,$45,$42,$48,$43,$44,$18,$23,$28,"+",$9,$33,"0" ; else print $2,"'"$chr"'",$4,$6,$5,$45,$42,$48,$43,$44,$18,$23,$28,"+",$9,$33,"1" }' ./out/expected_dcct_1kg_only${chr}_${chunk}.res > ./temp/expected_dcct_1kg_chr${chr}_${chunk}.tmp
```

I was hoping to see the line:

Marker Chr BP .... 1

on the first line only, but somehow it seems to be printed for every record.

This is a snapshot of the output:

```
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
rs7002152   8   145000056   C   T   0.937422    0.984021    0.165311    0.71094 1.362   1304    79  1225    +   0.981763    0.309615    0
MARKER  CHR BP  EA  NEA EAF P   OR  SE  OR_95L  OR95U   N   N_CASES N_CONTROLS  STRAND  INFO    HWE_P   IMPUTED
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you did not put your `print` in the `BEGIN`. All you have in the `BEGIN` block is `OFS="\t"`. Which, by the way, means you don't need to add `"\t"` to your `print` call. So, what you're after is (I changed the formatting a bit for clarity):

```awk
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; 
            print "MARKER", "CHR", "BP", "EA", "NEA","EAF", "P","OR","SE", 
             "OR_95L","OR95U", "N","N_CASES", "N_CONTROLS", "STRAND","INFO", 
             "HWE_P","IMPUTED"
        }
FNR>16 && $45!="NA" && $9>=0.4 { 
    if ($1=="---") print $2,"'"$chr"'",$4,$6, $5,$45,$42,$48, 
                     $43,$44,$18,$23, $28,"+",$9,$33,"0" ; 
    else print $2,"'"$chr"'",$4,$6,$5,$45, $42,$48,$43,$44,$18, 
               $23,$28,"+",$9,$33,"1" 
}' ./out/expected_dcct_1kg_only${chr}_${chunk}.res > \
  ./temp/expected_dcct_1kg_chr${chr}_${chunk}.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in AWK, everything which is enclosed in BEGIN block is done prior to actual data manipulation. When you put some commands outside of BEGIN block it will start to influence your data processing.

The same goes for END block. END block is executed after all data is processed.